DO there exist solutions to $a^2+b^2-c^2=1$
I was trying to calculate energy jumps in hydrogen atoms that would be of the same energy difference, and I ended up with something of the form:
$$1/n_1^2+1/n_4^2=1/n_2^2+1/n_3^2$$
Where $n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4$ are the principle quantum numbers.
After a bit rearranging we get essentially :
"Find solutions to :$$a^2+b^2-c^2=1$$ for $a,b,c,d \in Q_{>0}$ with the additional condition that $a<1$."
Pls Guide me here onwards. I will be grateful for a solution.
PS: As per the solution posted below , we can now reduce to finding pythagorean triplets. So now I know there exists (infinitely many) solutions to the equation . For example, $(5/13,20/13,16/13)$ is a valid solutions.
$\textbf{However now what I Want to find out is that for}$ $n_1,n_2,n_3 and n_4$ positive integers such that $n_1$ not equal to $n_3$ and $n_2$ not equal to $n_4$ satisfying
$$1/n_1^2+1/n_4^2=1/n_2^2+1/n_3^2$$
$\textbf{What is the minimum value}$ of $ min(n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4)$ and the solution corresponding to it.
(Also, assume hypothetically that all the $n_i$'s are unbounded).
Thanks in advance!

Are $n_i$s necessarily unique values?

Yes, because they represent transitions of electrons from different energy levels.

What is that $d$?

$a^2 + b^2 -c^2 = 1\implies a^2 = (c-b)(c+b)+1$. As $c-b$ and $c+b$ can be any integers so long as they are both even or odd (and if both are odd we can have $c-b=1$) so all we need is $a^2$ be an even square or one more than a number divisible by $4$.  If I pick $a=13$ just as a lark. I get $169=168+1$ and $168=6\times 28$ (or any other two even factors) So let $c$ be $17$ (half we between $6$ and $28$) and $b=11$ (so $17-11=6$ and $17+11=28$)  we have $13^3 + 11^2-17^2 =1$.   No need for pythagoren triplets.

Trivial solutions include $a$ or $b$ being $1$ and the other two being equal. 

For nontrivial solutions, if you let all the variables have the same denominator $d$ (or just multiply each variable by the least common denominator, really), the problem reduces to $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ over $\mathbb{Z}^+$. In other words, Pythagorean triples with the same hypotenuse. There's a good discussion of these triples on this post. Hope that helps!

There's no reason for this to come from Pythagorean triples, because the common value doesn't have to be a square, e.g. $5^2+5^2=7^2+1^2$.

@EspeciallyLime you're right, my bad.

With the condition $n_1<n_2<n_3<n_4$, the solution of $\frac{1}{n_1^2}+\frac{1}{n_4^2}=\frac{1}{n_2^2}+\frac{1}{n_3^2}$ has a minimum $n_1$ value of $5$, and such a solution is given by
$$\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{90^2}=\frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{1}{9^2}$$
Why is this the minimal $n_1$?
If $n_1 = 1$, then $n_2$ and $n_3$ can't be less than $2$ and $3$ respectively, and so $\frac{1}{n_2^2}+\frac{1}{n_3^2}\le \frac14+\frac19<1<\frac{1}{n_1^2}+\frac{1}{n_4^2}$ since $n_1=1$ in this case.
Similar arguments hold for $n_1=2$ (with $n_2,n_3$ being at least $3$ and $4$ respectively) and for $n_1=3$ (with $n_2,n_3$ being at least $4$ and $5$ respectively).
For $n_1=4$, we have that $n_2$ and $n_3$ must be at least $5$ and $6$ respectively. Although $\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{6^2}>\frac{1}{4^2}$, there is no integer value of $n_4$ that completes a solution to $\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{n_4^2}=\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{6^2}$. In all other situations, we have that $n_2 \ge 5$ and $n_3 \ge 7$, but $\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2} < \frac{1}{4^2}$, and so as in the previous cases, we get no solutions.
So indeed $n_1=5$ is minimal, with a specific solution proposed above.

I am a novice at number theory, but fortunately the constraints of your problem help establish an approach. We would still have to do some guessing, though.
Let us start from your equation of principal quantum numbers. We can rewrite it this way:
$$(n_2 n_3 n_4)^2 + (n_1 n_2 n_3)^2 = (n_1 n_3 n_4)^2 + (n_1 n_2 n_4)^2 $$
We know that $n_i$'s are distinct integer values (thank you for clarifying), and because they are principal quantum numbers, I assume none of them is larger than 9.
The above equation tells us that each $n_i$ should be a divisor of the product the other three. For example, if we take $n_1$, we see that it is a divisor of every summation term except the left-most. Therefore, $n_1$ should be a divisor of $n_2 n_3 n_4$.
This allows us to narrow down our search. We can tell, for example, that none of $n_i$'s can be 5 or 7. Here are possible sets that satisfy the criterion of the above paragraph:
$$1, 2, 4, 8$$
$$1, 2, 3, 6$$
$$2, 3, 4, 6$$
$$2, 3, 6, 9$$
I am going to make a simplifying guess here and assume that the first and last sets are out of your scope because they contain very high principal quantum numbers.
Looking at the remaining two sets, I also eliminate the one containing $1$, because the sums of squares of inverses of any other other two numbers in the set is smaller than $1$.
Finally, we are left with the set $2, 3, 4, 6$. Unfortunately, it is not possible to establish $\frac{1}{n_1^2} + \frac{1}{n_4^2} = \frac{1}{n_2^2} + \frac{1}{n_3^2}$ with any combination of these numbers either. We didn't get an answer, but at least we have an approach.

Thanks, however we are not assuming n_1<9. Sorry for the late clarification.

Given rational $c$   we can parametrize  $x^2 + y^2 = 1 + c^2 $   by what we call stereographic projection. Given integers $u,v$  with $\gcd(u,v)=1$ (and not both zero)    take $x = 1 + t u, \; \; $ $y = c + t v$   for some rational $t.$  To solve     $x^2 + y^2 = 1 + c^2 $  we get $$  (2u+2cv)t + ( u^2 + v^2)t^2 = 0 $$
so that the nonzero value for $t$  is
$$  t = \frac{-2(u+cv)}{u^2 + v^2}  $$
For $x=1+tu$    we need
$$  tu = \frac{-2u^2 - 2cuv}{u^2 + v^2}  $$  and
$$ 1 =  \frac{u^2 + v^2}{u^2 + v^2}   $$   and
$$ x =   \frac{-u^2 - 2cuv + v^2}{u^2 + v^2}  $$
For   $y = c + t v$   we need
$$ c =  \frac{cu^2 + cv^2}{u^2 + v^2}   $$   and
$$  tv = \frac{-2uv - 2cv^2}{u^2 + v^2}  $$
so
$$ y =  \frac{cu^2 -2uv - cv^2}{u^2 + v^2}   $$

I'm surprised no-one is suggesting the easiest way to solve.
$a^2 + b^2 -c^2 = 1$
$a^2 = 1 +(c^2-b^2) = 1+(c-b)(c+b)$.
If we rewrite $c-b$ as $m$ and $c+b$ as $m+2b=n$ we can have $a^2 = mn+1$ where $mn$ is any number that is a product of two numbers of the same even/oddness.  That number can even be an odd prime (as $p = 1\times p$).  The only thing it can't be is an even composite not divisible by $4$.
But $1$ less than a square is in never an even not divisible by $4$ because $a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$ and $a-1,a+2$ are both even or both odd.
Sooo.....
Let $a$ be any number.  Say... of the top of my head... $42$... then $42^2 = 1 + 1763$.  Factor that any way you want.  Say $1$ and $1763$.  Let $m =1$ and $1763 = 1+2b$ so $b=881$ and $m=1=c-b$ so $c=882$ and we have $42^2 + 881^2 - 882^2 = 1$. (Punch it into a calculator)

As @mikhail writes we can consider the equation $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2,$ where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z^+.$ This can be rewritten as
$a^2-c^2=d^2-b^2,$
i.e. $(a+c)(a-c)=(d+b)(d-b).$
Thus, given $a>c>0$ we shall look at different factorizations of $a^2-c^2.$
For example, with $a=11,\ c=3$ we have $a^2-c^2=121-9=112$ with (among others) factorizations $14\times 8$ and $28\times 4.$ Asserting $d+b=28,\ d-b=4$ gives $d=16,\ b=12.$ So $11^2+12^2=3^2+16^2\ (=265).$
